# C# WinForm KeyPress Enter key not fire after link clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keypress

Here is simple code in windowsForm

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("LOLOLO");
       if (e.KeyChar == 13)
       {
         panel3.Visible = true;
       }
    }
```

And i have Panel control with link which close this panel

```
private void linkLabel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel3.Visible = false;
}
```

I'ts work When i press any key it show me MessageBox but when i press ENTER my Panel is open.
Problem is when i mouse clicked linkLabel2 to close Panel, any keys fire keyPress event, except ENTER key. When i press ENTER nothing to do, keyPress event not fire

How to fix it?

Comment: [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to enable key Form.KeyPreview Property in form1.

At the end, when you click linkLabel2, it got focus and stay there. You have to leave focus. I've added and event to leave focus from linkLable2, just when you press Enter, it does not call linkLabel2 again. If it works, please mark as read and vote up. Thanks

```
private void linkLabel2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Visible = false;

            linkLabel2_Leave(linkLabel2, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code not work, I've added this.ActiveControl = null; inside linkLabel2_Click event and now works perfectlly!

```
private void linkLabel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.ActiveControl = null;
   panel3.Visible = false;
}
```